# How to poll another server from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, shopify

I'm currently developing a Shopify app with Node/Express and a Postgres database. When a user registers an account and connects their Shopify store, I'll need to download all of their store's orders. They could have 100,000s of orders, so I'd like to use a [Shopify GraphQL Bulk Operation](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries). While Shopify is handling this, my Node server will need to poll the Shopify server to check on the progress, and when the operation is complete, Shopify will send me a link where I can download all of the data. Once the data is processed and stored in my database, I'll send the user an email to say that their account is now set up.

How should I handle polling the Shopify server? The process could take anywhere from a few mins to hours. Using `setInterval()` would be a bad idea right? Because if the server restarts for whatever reason, It will lose the interval? So, should I use some sort of background task? And would I need to store anything in my database? I've researched cron jobs, child processes, worker threads, [the bull package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull) -- and it's left me a little confused.

(I also know that I could use a webhook, but Shopify offers no guarantees that my app will receive the webhook.)

Comment: From the site you linked `Subscribing to the webhook topic is recommended over polling as it limits the number of redundant API calls.` https://shopify.dev/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries#step-2-wait-for-the-operation-to-finish

Comment: The same page also says "Webhook delivery isn't always guaranteed, so you might still need to poll for the operation's status to check when it's finished."

Comment: So I would recommend using cron

Comment: So for every user that creates an account, I should create a separate cron job to poll Shopify, then when I receive the data I should destroy the cron?

Comment: I would rather create a list of accounts to check and poll each. Then when data is received you can remove it.

Comment: Shopify gave you permission to download a customer's entire order history eh? Wow! You must've provided a decent excuse to get that! They don't hand that out to just anyone. Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

Upon installation, launch a background job labeled "GetCustomerOrders". As you know, background jobs are mature, and nicely handle problems. For example, they can retry themselves if something goes wrong.

The Background job itself just sets up the Bulk Download and then settles into Poll. Polling is no big deal and just happens. As you said, could be minutes, could take hours. Nevertheless, a poll gets status on a bulk download, and that can even be hot-rodded. For example, you poll with an ID. So you poll till that ID completes. Regardless of restarts.

At the end of that rather simple setup, you get an URL to download and parse JSON. Spawn another job even for that. Endless fun. Why sweat it? Background jobs are the way to go.

The Webhook idea is OK but as the documentation says, they are not 100% and CRON is bush-league in that it misses out on the mature development of jobs in queues and is more like a simple trigger. Relying on CRON to start something is fine, but gives you zero management over what it starts.

I am guessing NodeJS has a decent background job system by this time. When you look at Sidekiq for Ruby you realize what awesome is. Surely you can find a copycat in Node that comes close anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to background tasks, so if anyone has any suggestions on how I could go about it in Node.js, that would be helpful.